# Erro "... is not a recognized built-in function name" no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Não estou conseguindo fazer um insert no banco SQL Server. Segue meu código:

```
INSERT INTO TB_Cadastro (Cod_Vac, CodIN,Produtor, Codmal, DataVac, DataCompra, NumDoc, SerieDoc, UFDoc, CodMunDoc, Lab, NumPartida, Validade, Revendedor, Doses, Qtde, Obs, tipo, Por, Qtde412Macho, Qtde1224Macho, Qtde2436Macho, Qtde36Macho, Qtde412Femea, Qtde1224Femea, Qtde2436Femea, Qtde36Femea, Campanha, CasaVet, CPFCNPJDoador, Origem, QtdeFiscalizada, TipoVacinacaoAnterior, Responsavel, NumTransfVac, ativo)
VALUES (5079,'5868','24936707287','',TO_DATE('2015-04-08 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('2015-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'072608 ','','14',1400100,'20557161000198','009/2014 ',TO_DATE('','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'11','30','','','','',6,1,0,0,3,2,14,2,'2/2015','','','','','5','','','');
```

> SQL Error [195] [42000]: 'TO_DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
>     java.sql.SQLException: 'TO_DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 2):

[TO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) é uma função usanda no ORACLE, a correspondente em sql server seria o uso do convert(datetime,'2015-04-08 00:00:00'), mas isso se sua data não tivesse no forma correto, como no exemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005780/converting-string-to-datetime-in-yyyymmdd-format).

```
select
   convert (datetime, '20111019')
from _table
```

Outra coisa que poderia ser usando é o

```
SET LANGUAGE { [ N ] 'language' | @language_var }
```

Caso o forma da data não estivesse no mesmo idioma do banco de dados.

Comment: +1, não sabia que era do Oracle. Corrigi minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

esse erro também pode ser resolvido colocando o nome do esquema do seu banco de dados.
exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A função `TO_DATE`, que você usa 3 vezes, não existe no SQL Server. <strike>Deve ser uma função personalizada disponível em outro BD, de onde esse código veio originalmente.</strike> Como ensinou o GOKU, é uma função do Oracle.

Você já está usando um formato de data que o SQL Server entende, então pode simplesmente substituir os casos assim:

> TO_DATE('2015-04-08 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

por simplesmente:

> '2015-04-08 00:00:00'